# Job Listeners and Trigger Listeners in Spring 3.1 and Quartz

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using Spring 3.0 and Quartz 1.6 JDBC Job Store for Job Scheduling. I want to generate email alerts when ever the triggers are misfired. How can Trigger misfire event listeners be configured in Spring Quartz ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Create a trigger listener with your code in triggerMisfired method:

```
package foo;

import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerListener;
import org.quartz.Trigger.CompletedExecutionInstruction;

public class MyTriggerListener implements TriggerListener {

    private String name;

    public MyTriggerListener(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void triggerComplete(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context,
            CompletedExecutionInstruction triggerInstructionCode) {

    }

    public void triggerFired(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {

    }

    public void triggerMisfired(Trigger trigger) {
        // here goes your code for sending email
    }

    public boolean vetoJobExecution(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {

        return false;
    }

}
```

There is also the alternative of extending TriggerListenerSupport and overriding only the triggerMisfired method:

```
public class MyTriggerListener extends TriggerListenerSupport {

    private String name;

    public MyOtherTriggerListener(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerMisfired(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
        // do something with the event
    }
}
```

2) add the listener bean to the spring configuration:

```
    <bean id="triggerListener"
            class="foo.MyTriggerListener">
    </bean>
```

and put the listener bean inside the SchedulerFactoryBean along with any other properties like triggers etc.

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    .....
    <property name="globalTriggerListeners">
        <list>
        <ref bean="triggerListener" />
        </list>
    </property>
    ...

   </bean>
```

Comment: I understand extending TriggerListener, but I think registering the listener to scheduler is not clear. If I use plain Quartz, I believe that is the way to go. But while using Spring-Quartz, I don't need scheduler at any place because every thing is managed by Spring, I dont need to meddle with any thing except Triggers and Jobs. Am I missing some thing here.

Comment: Hi kiran, I edited the answer to include the spring configuration, sorry it was not clear for me that was your problem. Adding the listener is made in a similar manner like you add the jobdetails and the triggers. You just put the bean in the spring-xml and reference it from the appropriate property of SchedulerFactoryBean

Comment: It gives Error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TriggerListener name cannot be empty.